# Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, npm-install, caniuse-lite

I am running node 16.19.0 on ubuntu-latest on Azure DevOps and using this yaml step prior to building my VueJS 2 solution:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

When the `npm run build` command fires I see this:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

And:

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

If I then add a step with command `npx browserslist@latest --update-db` after the `npm install` line, that step outputs:

```
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: browserslist@4.21.5
Latest version:     1.0.30001457
Installed version:  none
Removing old caniuse-lite from lock file
Installing new caniuse-lite version
$ npm install caniuse-lite
```

And then:

```
Problem with `npm install caniuse-lite` call. Run it manually.
```

I am running it as manually as I can, on the Azure pipe, that is.